# How to get ContentTypeReader to work for Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, xna

I am trying to get a content type reader for my class working, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Is there anything I need to do to get this to work?

```
public class Map
{

    ...

    /// <summary>
    /// Read a Map object from the content pipeline.
    /// </summary>
    public class MapReader : ContentTypeReader<Map>
    {
        protected override Map Read(ContentReader input, Map existingInstance)
        {
            Map map = existingInstance;
            if (map == null)
            {
                map = new Map();
            }

            map.TileSetFile = input.ReadString();
            map.Dimensions = input.ReadObject<Point>();
            map.Tiles = input.ReadObject<int[]>();

            map.Load(input.ContentManager);

            return map;
        }
    }
}
```

The xml is read in properly, but the Read function seems to not be called. Any ideas?

Do I need more than just what I have here.

Comment: Is this throwing an exception when you try to use it?

Comment: No, it just seems to ignore the code entirely. Do I have to register it some how?

Comment: Do you have a matching ContentTypeWriter for this Map type? On that type, you'd have to register your runtime reader class.

Comment: This is all I have. What else do I need and where should I put it? I just want to be able to execute code automatically when I load this file so it can load a dependent file.

Comment: I will post an answer tomorrow.

Comment: Where this answer you promised?

Comment: Sorry i had a hectic time at work. Will post my full answer today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Disclaimer: I am by no means an expert on the XNA Content Pipeline***

Before giving a short summary on the content pipeline and how to extend it, i'd like to mention that since XNA 3.1, implementing a ContentTypeReader and ContentTypeWriter is no longer necessary.

In XNA 3.1, Automatic XNB serialization was introduced (by using Reflection), and so if you do not include any writer and reader, XNA will take care of that for you (i believe excluding some cases).

Read more here: [Automatic XNB Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.content.pipeline.serialization.compiler.contenttypewriter.getruntimereader%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx)

The XNA Content Pipeline is a process that is made of the following steps:

[image]

Most of these occur at design time (when you are using Visual Studio to add art assets to your game and when you're building your game). The last part is executed at runtime, when you run your game and call Content.Load to load your assets.

The XNA Content Pipeline, being open for extension, allows you to support more than the built in content types that are shipped with the XNA Framework, and so allows you to introduce new content types and new file formats to be processed as input for your game.

In the following diagram, you can see the chain of events that are executing when extending the content pipeline:

[image]

In order to create an extension to support a new type (Map in your example), you must do the following (some of which i suppose you already did):

1. Create a new Content Pipeline extension library project in VS.
2. Add this project as a reference to your game's content project.
3. Add a new ContentImporter, ContentProcessor [optional] ContentTypeWriter and ContentTypeReader
4. Your ContentTypeWriter class should implement this method:

   ```
   public override string GetRuntimeReader(TargetPlatform targetPlatform)
       {
           // TODO: change this to the name of your ContentTypeReader
           // class which will be used to load this data.
           return "ContentPipelineExtension.CharacterReader, ContentPipelineExtension, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral";
       }
   ```

Note that in this example, i've used some other CharacterReader class, you will have to register your reader type with it's full name and containing assembly.

Read about the GetRuntimeReader method here: [ContentTypeWriter.GetRuntimeReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.content.pipeline.serialization.compiler.contenttypewriter.getruntimereader%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx)

I havev created a demo project with a new type called Character, an importer, processor and reader/writer for it.

You can get it here: [Sample project](http://www.4shared.com/file/Euq5OVLV/ContentPipelineSample.html)

*note that you can put this line in your processor/importer in order to debug and see that visual studio is actually triggering the code for your Content Pipeline extension library.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

*Another thing to note is that your new type (Map, Character, whatever) should be defined in its own shared assembly and planned correctly, since this type should be used both in your actual Game and in your Content Pipeline extension library.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You said "implementing a ContentTypeReader and ContentTypeWriter is no longer necessary" and you are right for the basic case. It is successfully loading all the data that is in the xml file. The only thing is, I want to be able to execute some code automatically during the load process to load some dependent files. For instance, I want my Map class to load a TileSet class, which will then load a Texture. Currently, I have to manually call the Load(ContentManager ) function I created. But I want it to be automatic. Isn't that what a ContentReader does?

Comment: See my classes: 
Map : http://xp-dev.com/sc/browse/81727/%2Ftrunk%2Fprojects%2FWindowsPhone%2FCrystalData%2FMap.cs?rev=421

Comment: TileSet - http://xp-dev.com/sc/browse/81727/%2Ftrunk%2Fprojects%2FWindowsPhone%2FCrystalData%2FTileSet.cs?rev=421

Comment: content reader is the runtime class that is used to actually load your XNB file. Whataver code u put there will be executed. See my sample solution.

Comment: Ok, I already have the content reader class, but I don't have a writer, importer or processor. Do I just need to add an importer class to get it working?

Comment: For your case, implement a writer, importer and processor. The writer should implement the GetRuntimeReader method to return your Reader type. This way at runtime the content manager will know which reader to pick and use.

Comment: Is there anyway to get the ContentReader set up without the ContentWriter? I am having project settings because I am using .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (not just regular 4) so it can't find XNA.Framework.Content.Pipeline. When I change it back, everything else seems to be broken. BTW I this is all for WindowsPhone 7.1 with the beta SDK.

Comment: As far as i know, these come in pairs (Reader/Writer). Client profile/windows phone are not related, the content project references the content pipeline project, which are all taking place in design time. The only code that runs on the phone is the content reader, which should have no issues. Try to create as i suggested. It is working.

Comment: Did you have success setting this up ?

Comment: No, it continued to not let me get it working together. I just gave up and I will do it manually with my function. I will give you the bounty for all your effort though. Thanks.